# User Controls in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, postback, repeater

I have a usercontrol that provides voting buttons (for a SO type voting model) - it contains a private int member that retains the id of the record. Outside a repeater, it functions just fine - postbacks work, and the correct id is retained in the user control.

Inside the repeater, an itemdatabound event handler associates the correct ID with the usercontrol and it works correctly - displays the correct vote count from the database. When one of the voting buttons is pressed, though, it fires a postback to the usercontrol and the control has lost the contents of its private int member so it no longer functions.

I've tried both re-databinding the usercontrol on postback, and binding it only on the initial load - the problem is the same both ways.

How do I get the usercontrol to retain the value of that int across postbacks?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried putting the value in viewstate ?

```
public string Id{
    get
    {
        return this.ViewState["Value"] == null ?
            0 :
            (int)this.ViewState["Value"];
    }
    set { this.ViewState["Value"] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I would think you've correctly identified the cause and the solution.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Any insight as to why I need to do that for the control in the repeater, but the same control works properly outside of it?

Comment: Private member variables in controls aren't serialized as part of the viewstate and thus aren't restored on postback.  The above solution is correct if you want to retain a private var in the viewstate.  Another option would be to use a hidden text box and then it would get automatically restored.

Comment: hm isn´t there a way to bind a usercontrol - I am looking for it now and I am sure I used it last time I did any webmagic. OnItemDataBind somehow.